# How to output all results from MongoDB's find() into jQuery's html()?

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, getjson

I am wanting to output all results generated from the MongoDB `find()` method into a `div` via jQuery's `getJSON()` method.

**Document**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("34576347347"),
   "content": "here is some content",
   "field2": {
     "subfield1": {
       "0": "sf1v0",
       "1": "sf1v1",
       "2": "sf1v2" 
    },
     "subfield2": "value 2" 
  },
   "field2": "value 3" 
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php   

$dbhost = 'username:password@127.x.xx.x:27017/';  
$dbname = 'my_database';  
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");  
$db = $m->$dbname;  

// specify the collection  
$collection = $db->myCollection;  

// define the query  
$query = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));  

foreach($query as $result) {  
echo $result['field2'] . " - " . $result['content'] . "<br>";  
}  

?>
```

When accessing the PHP file directly it displays:

```
value 3 - here is some content // values from the first document
value 3 - here is some content // values from the second document
```

Below are my attempts to get the same output in a `div` via jQuery's `getJSON()` method.

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://path/to/file.php", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){  
$("#my_div").html(results);
});
```

**Other Things I've Tried**

Using the `iterator_to_array()` function:

**PHP**

```
// define the query  
$query = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));  
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($query, false));
```

**Result**

The div's content changes to an empty div ie:

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

This following gets a result:

**PHP**

```
// define the query  
$query = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));  
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($query, false));
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#my_div").html(results[0].field2 + " - " + results[0].content + "<br>" + results[1].field2 + " - " + results[1].content);
```

But it is not a scalable/flexible solution.

I am thinking I need to use jQuery's `.each()` and `.append()` methods so that:

- for each Document in the array
- Append its content to the div

But I can't figure out how to do it yet, this is what i've tried:

```
$.getJSON("http://path/to/file.php", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){ 
$("#my_div").html("");
$.each(results, function(){ 
$("#my_div").append(results.field2 + " - " + results.content + "<br>");
});
});
```

It is outputting:

```
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

**PHP**

```
<?php   

$dbhost = 'username:password@127.x.xx.x:27017/';  
$dbname = 'my_database';  
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");  
$db = $m->$dbname;  

// specify the collection  
$collection = $db->myCollection;  

// define the query  
$query = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));  

//  add content type (otherwise firebug doesn't show a JSON tab and type is text/html)
header("Content-type: application/json");

// convert the cursor to an array
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($query, false));

?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://path/to/file.php", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){ 
$("#my_div").html("");
$.each(results, function(key,value){ 
$("#my_div").append(results.field2 + " - " + results.content + "<br>");
});
});
```

Will display the content of `my_div` as:

```
value 3 - here is some content
value 3 - here is some content
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll have to extract all of the resulting documents from the cursor you created after executing the query. What I've done in my example below is prepared an array to hold all of the documents the cursor points to.

After you have this array of docuemnts, all you really have to do is encode the results into JSON format. For this you can use the [`json_encode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

> **`json_encode()`** -  Returns the JSON representation of a value

Here is an example usage:

```
$cursor = $collection->find( YOUR_QUERY );  
$response = [];
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
  $response[] = $document;
}

echo json_encode( $response );
```

Comment: It is more the jQuery side of things that I think I need to get working.  When I use `json_encode()` as demonstrated above, and then jQery's `getJSON()` as demonstrated in original post, changes are not being made to the HTML content of the specified div.  Firebug shows the `response` as two JSON objects, although there is no specific JSON tab.  I tried adding `header("Content-type: application/json");` above the echo to enforce things but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Could you please add the contents of `$query` to your original question?

Comment: Your answer needs to exhaust the cursor before it json_encodes it because the results from mongodb are not an assoc array, they are infact a resource of a server-side cursor

Comment: Another way is to use `iterator_to_array($query,false)` it is much cleaner and only one line of code

Comment: I think both of the above suggestions add the JSON objects to an array, I've update the original post to show the results of using the `iterator_to_array()` function.

Comment: I am going to look into iterating over JSON objects in an array in jQuery as I think that's what needs to happen, I have added more attempts to original post.